# Unable to Scroll Navigation item till end in android

Tags: android

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">


        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btn_sing_in"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-55dp"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btn_sing_in"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/logout_height"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/logout_drawable_padding"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_logout"
                android:gravity="start|center"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/logout_padding_start"
                android:text="@string/nav_item_logout" />
        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            tools:context="com.kdcos.contsync.view.dashboard.DashboardActivity">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:elevation="0dp"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


                    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="56dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector_view"
                        app:itemTextColor="@color/selector_view_text"
                        app:menu="@menu/nav_bottom" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view_divider"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
                        android:background="@color/colorMenuGrey"
                        android:paddingBottom="12dp" />

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_above="@id/view_divider"
                        android:background="@color/colorWhite"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/baseline_grid_8x"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin_end"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dialpad" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this is navheader:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/baseline_grid_22x"
        android:background="@color/colorCallGradientEnd"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/baseline_grid_2.5x"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/baseline_grid_2.5x"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/baseline_grid_2.5x"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_6.5x"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">


        <com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/baseline_grid_8x"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/baseline_grid_8x"
            android:src="@drawable/illustration"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <!--app:image_url="@{viewModel.profilePic}"-->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userNameText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Kushal Dalal"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lnUpgradelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/userNameText"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/baseline_grid_2x"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_2x"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_upgrade_btn"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.navigateToonUpgardePage()}"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold">l


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
                android:text="Upgrade to Premium"
                android:textColor="#351600"
                android:textSize="14.4sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

this is my xml i am displaying 9 item and one nave header but in bigger device i am able to display all 9 item including navheader but in smaller device its display 8 item and nav header when i try to scroll its display till 8 the item it hides 9 item in bottom please check  and suggest me how to fix this i am not able to find where is issue coming why its not display 9th which is last item in small device .

Comment: It probably seems like that because of that `TextView` you've stuck inside the `NavigationView`. That's not how `NavigationView` is meant to be used. Temporarily remove the `TextView` to see if that's your issue.

Comment: which textview you are talking about

Comment: yes correct but i have to set that is in footer can u please tell me how to add that logout textview in footer @MikeM.

Comment: If you want it pinned to the bottom, not scrolling, then pull the `TextView` out of the `NavigationView`, and put them both inside another `ViewGroup` that will be the drawer; e.g., a vertical `LinearLayout`. Just make sure to move the `layout_gravity` attribute from the `NavigationView` to that new `ViewGroup`, because that's what designates it as the drawer.